# coinFlip then find the longest streak of the heads - Java

Tags: java

I was working on this codeHS AP CompSci problem (4.3.6)

Basically I have to simulate flipping a coin 100 times, printing out the result (heads or tails) but in the end I need to print out the longest streak of heads.

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;

    boolean tailsChosen = true;
    int count_tails=0;
    int count_heads=0;
    int streak = 1; 
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i= 1; i<=100; i++)
        {
            tailsChosen= Randomizer.nextBoolean();

            if (tailsChosen) 
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                count_tails++;     
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                count_heads++;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + streak );
    }
}
```

This is my coding so far. I have worked so that I can randomly printout 100 heads and tails but just cannot find a way to find the longest streak of heads..

Thank you

Comment: keep a few counters, one that holds longest headsStreak, one with longest tailStreak, and then currentStreak and currentType.
if type changes: currentStreak > longestStreak(ofType) overwrite and start counting for the new type

Comment: Or increment on "head" and reset on "tail" and keep the last value if it is bigger than the previous streak.

Comment: I would create two variables `headStreak` and `tailStreak`  If `tailsChosen` is true, then unconditionally set `headStreak` to `zero` and vice-verse

Comment: `public static final int FLIPS = 100;` - Nice idea, follow through

Comment: @ScaryWombat didn't even seen the constant, too bad it is not used in the loop :/

Answer (score 1):

You may increase the streak when it is a head and reset it to 0 if it is a tail. Then you compare it with the previous maxHeadStreak.

```
int streak = 0; // should be init to zero
// other codes
for (int i= 1; i<=FLIPS; i++) // use your constant
{
    tailsChosen= Randomizer.nextBoolean();

    if (tailsChosen) 
    {
        System.out.println("Tails");
        count_tails++;     
        streak = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Heads");
        count_heads++;
        streak++;
        maxHeadStreak = Math.max(streak, maxHeadStreak);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `max_head_streak` variable for storing the maximal streak of heads achieved so far. The `count_heads` variable is incremented every time heads is flipped.

As soon as tails is flipped and the head streak is broken check whether your current head streak is higher than your maximal head streak and if it is set `max_head_streak` to the current `count_heads`. Afterwards set current heads count `count_heads` back to 0.

After you flipped 100 coins print `max_head_streak`.

```
public static final int FLIPS = 100;

boolean tailsChosen = true;
int max_head_streak=0;
int count_heads=0;
public void run()
    {
        for (int i= 1; i<=FLIPS; i++)
        {
            tailsChosen= Randomizer.nextBoolean();

            if (tailsChosen) 
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                if (max_head_streak < count_heads)
                {
                    max_head_streak = count_heads;
                {
                count_heads = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                count_heads++;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + max_head_streak);
}
```

Some remarks:

- You can omit the `tails_count` since you don't need to count tails.
- You define the number of flips in the beginning but never use it.
  Just put `FLIPS` into your loop declaration.

Comment: You've put max_heads_count = count_heads; but I think you meant max_heads_streak = count_heads; right? and Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this problem for so long!

Comment: Yes you are right, I got the variable names confused. I corrected them now. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also, may I know the logic behind the max_heads_streak? I dont get the if statement if (max_heads_streak < count_heads) part. Wouldn't max_heads_streak always be lower than the count_heads?                  
  Since we only declared that it is 0, but did not put any increments or anything... Thanks again

Comment: `max_heads_streak` is 0 only the first time we compare it to `heads_count`. If it is lower we assign the value of the higher `heads_count` to it. So `max_heads_streak` is updated every time we observe a new higher streak.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;

    public void run()
    {
        int headStreak = 0;
        int longestHeadStreak = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (Randomizer.nextBoolean())
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                headStreak++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                if (longestHeadStreak < headStreak)
                {
                    longestHeadStreak = headStreak;
                }
                headStreak = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + longestHeadStreak);

    }
}
```

Comment: easy peezy bro!

Comment: all you need to do is change the 10 in the for loop to a 100

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do.

Essentially, keep track of the length of the current streak (you clearly realised that) and then keep track of it's maxima.

```
public class LongestStreak {
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean lastFlip = true;
    int count_tails = 0;
    int count_heads = 0;
    int streak = 0;
    int longestTailsStreak = 0;
    int longestHeadsStreak = 0;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= FLIPS; i++) {
            // Flip the coin.
            boolean itsTails = random.nextBoolean();

            // Keep track of the length of the current streak.
            if (itsTails == lastFlip) {
                // The streak continues.
                streak += 1;
            } else {
                // End of streak.
                if (itsTails) {
                    // It must have been a run of heads.
                    longestHeadsStreak = Math.max(longestHeadsStreak, streak);
                } else {
                    // It must have been a run of tails.
                    longestTailsStreak = Math.max(longestTailsStreak, streak);
                }
                streak = 0;
            }
            // Count them.
            if (itsTails) {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                count_tails += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                count_heads += 1;
            }
            lastFlip = itsTails;
        }
        System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + longestHeadsStreak);
        System.out.println("Longest streak of tails: " + longestTailsStreak);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In JavaScript:



 function longestHeadsStreak(arr) {
    let headsStreak = 0; 
    let longestStreak = 0; 
    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++) {
     int x = i + 1
     if(arr[i] == "Heads") {
      headStreak++
      }
      if(arr[x] != "Heads") {
       if(longestStreak < headsStreak) {
         var longestStreak = 0;
         longestStreak += headsStreak;
         }
         headsStreak = 0;
         }
console.log("Longest Streak of Heads: " + longestStreak);
}
```